# Javascript JSON parsing not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code to parse values from a JSON API. I'm trying to access the values in an array, but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property "results" from undefined. (line 24)`.

My code is as follows:

```
function getItemID(searchTerm) {
  var fetchUrl = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/" + escape(searchTerm) + "?exclude_unsellable=1";

  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchUrl);

  var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();

  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;

  for(i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++){
    if(jsonObject.results[i].name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm.toLowerCase()){
      return jsonObject.results[i].data_id;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The URL I'm trying to parse is here: http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/ash%20dye?exclude_unsellable=1

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "total": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "data_id": 20357,
            "name": "Ash Dye",
            "rarity": 4,
            "restriction_level": 0,
            "img": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/6E262204244D033C2C38DF3F026654B49BFE4EA4/66650.png",
            "type_id": 3,
            "sub_type_id": 6,
            "price_last_changed": "2015-06-15 16:14:05 UTC",
            "max_offer_unit_price": 15513,
            "min_sale_unit_price": 22863,
            "offer_availability": 597,
            "sale_availability": 99,
            "sale_price_change_last_hour": 0,
            "offer_price_change_last_hour": 0
        },
        {
            "data_id": 20443,
            "name": "Squash Dye",
            "rarity": 2,
            "restriction_level": 0,
            "img": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/06DF4AD10F92FDC3AB0EA1D8411038D44758BD52/66654.png",
            "type_id": 3,
            "sub_type_id": 6,
            "price_last_changed": "2015-06-15 16:14:15 UTC",
            "max_offer_unit_price": 222,
            "min_sale_unit_price": 457,
            "offer_availability": 1071,
            "sale_availability": 572,
            "sale_price_change_last_hour": 0,
            "offer_price_change_last_hour": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: basic debugging: `console.log(jsonObject)`  to see what you got back... plus, you're doing `JSON.parse(...).result`, so **UNLESS* that sit returns `obj.result.results`, you're already digging "down" into the database before you ever start looping.

Comment: Remove `.result` from the `jsonObject` assignment. Otherwise, you're basically doing `JSON.parse(jsonString).result.results`

Comment: There is a typo error (but it's another issue, not the one you posted). Change from `JSON.parse(jsonString).result;` to `JSON.parse(jsonString).results;` (missing s)

Comment: Can you post what your `jsonData` looks like?

Comment: @Tao, it is not a missing "s" problem

Comment: @VitoShadow I know. It's another issue, not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some *typo errors* and *redundant property access*. You need to change from

```
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;

 for(i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++){
     if(jsonObject.results[i].name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm.toLowerCase()){
        return jsonObject.results[i].data_id;
     }
 }
```

To this:

```
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).results;

 for(i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++){
     if(jsonObject[i].name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm.toLowerCase()){
        return jsonObject[i].data_id;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! I can't believe I actually missed this error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [your JSON data](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/ash%20dye?exclude_unsellable=1), `results` is a property of `jsonObject`, not of `jsonObject.result` (that is actually `undefined`).

So you should solve by replacing this line:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;
```

with this:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: I am very dumb. I copied the snippet from an example and I figured that was a part of the JSON parsing process.

Comment: please, accept and/or upvote the answer if it is correct

Comment: I went for another answer that condensed the code a bit more